# A compute instance having network network outages repeatedly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We have a compute instance that is repeatedly having network outages. It's a part of the cluster so that's an incredible pain. It really feels like it's a problem with GC infrastructure (what else would it be) but apparently there's no way to contact them unless you pay support? How do you troubleshoot things like that?

Comment: What exact errors you are getting during these outages? Have you checked the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) output during this outage? [This](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips) help center article describes tips that you might find helpful if you run into problems using Google Compute Engine.  Additionally, if you think its a defect with GCP, I would recommend you to create a defect report using the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) along with all error report

Comment: The problem was that network was going down frequently during few hours. After that it got resolved. I guess the correct answer here would be if I can ensure Google knows about the problem somehow. I don't think this classifies as issue but it could be a hardware error or misconfiguration and it's not always the case it can be discovered by automatic monitoring. It's a pain they don't have any channel that would let me simply inform them the issue is happening. Or do they?

Comment: I would recommend to use the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to report this as a bug(with reproduction steps or error logs(if any)). If the Engineering team reproduce the issue, it will forward to the appropriate team for deep investigation.